# Does mysql LIKE get applied last if there's also an AND against an id field?

Tags: mysql, where-clause, sql-like

I have a MySQL query that looks something like this:

```
select * from cust_comment where note LIKE '%awesome%' and userId=222;
```

Let's assume that the `note` field is varchar(255) and `userId` is an int.

The most efficient way to execute this, in my opinion, would be for MySQL to filter on the `userId` first and then apply the `LIKE`. Does MySQL do this by default (automatically) or do you have to coerce it to do this or is there another way to make this happen?

Bonus answers: How would the answer to this question differ if `userId` had an index against it?

More info: I am planning on putting a full-text index against the `note` field but this may not be possible in the near future so `LIKE` is being used as a temporary workaround.

Comment: Best way to find out is EXPLAIN PLAN.

Comment: MySQL optimize query itself so I think it will do that (check int fields before string ones). And userId which is a foreign key should be indexed. Explain is more usefull when query uses joins... After a test I confirm that MySQL optimize where clause order

Comment: MySQL's optimizer is good enough to choose the best execution plan  without forcing it to do things you might consider better (like forcing an index etc.). Now, the data set will be reduced if an index lookup can be applied - there are cases when it can't be applied. In your case, it would look up records based on `userId` first, **if** it were an index. If both columns are **not** indexes, it does the table scan and looks up both values in both columns - order is really irrelevant here, since it's a hugely inefficient operation to begin with and both conditions have to be met.

Answer (score 2):

Most probably MySQL first reduces the result by `userId`, because `LIKE` is expensive and commonly less selective.

Even more probably when there is an index on `userId`, because this may speed up look up.

Nevertheless I would not count on that, because when MySQL knows from its statistics that `userId` is for whatever reason very low selective it may be superior to first reduce result by `note` instead of `userId`. It may also be possible that MySQL prefers a full table scan in such a case instead of using an existing index. A possible case is when every row in the table has `userId=222`.

Index on `note` does not make a difference here, because `LIKE '%...'` can never make use of an index. For `LIKE '%...%'`-patterns with more than 3 characters between the `%` MySQL uses *Turbo Boyer-Moore algorithm* to speed up search.

Answer (score 2):

The most efficient way to execute this query is to use an index:

```
create index idx_cust_comment_userid on cust_coment(userid)
```

In this case, the `userId` comparison will happen first.

With both clauses in the `where`, I do not know if MySQL attempts to optimize the order of evaluations.  Comparing integers is a bit faster than comparing strings (although this would be mitigated if the strings were quite short).  Compared to a full table scan, however, the difference in performance is probably not important.